# Finding limit of sequence to converge to the $L^1$ norm of $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f \in L^1(m)$ ($m$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$), I'd like to show that $$\sum_{-n^2}^{n^2} \left|\int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} f \,dm\,\right| \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_\Bbb R |\,f\,| \,dm$$.

Intuitively I see why this is true. As $m$ gets larger we're covering both a wider and finer evaluation of the integral of $f$. I suppose we can somehow compare $f$ to a simple $\phi$ in $L^1$: $\int |\phi - f| < \epsilon$.

We also have that for sufficiently large $m\in \mathbb N$, $$\sum_{-m^2}^{m^2} \left|
\int_{-j/n}^{(j+1)/n} f \,dm\,\right| \leq \int_\Bbb R |f| \,dm$$.

Therefore $$ \int_\Bbb R |f| \,dm - \sum_{-n^2}^{n^2} |\int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} f \,dm| = \int_{(-\infty,-n]\cup [n,\infty)} |f| \,dm + \int_{-n}^n |f| - \sum_{-n^2}^{n^2} |\int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} f | < $$

$$< \varepsilon + \sum_{-n^2}^{n^2} \int_{j/n}^{(j+1)/n} |f| - |\int_{j/m}^{(j+1)/m} f |$$.

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Another thought is to approximate $f$ with a continuous $g_m \in L^1([-m,m])$, though I am not sure how to write out the technical details.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but any subsequence $m_k$ with each one dividing the next, like $m_k=2^k$ or $m_k=k!$, gives an increasing sequence of values on the left-hand side. Since it's bounded above as you note, it has to converge to a limit. (But I guess proving these subsequential limits are correct doesn't help with the whole problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.**

1. As you have already observed, you can reduce the problem to the case where $f$ is supported in a closed interval $[-M,M]$, as the integral of $|f|$ in the rest of $\mathbb R$ can become arbitrarily small. In particular $\int_{|x|>M}|f|\,dm<\varepsilon$.
2. For any $f\in L^1[-M,M]$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $n$, and $c_j$ constants and $A_j\subset [-M,M]$ measurable sets, such that
   $$
   \int_{-M}^M\left|\,f-\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\chi_{A_i}\,\right|\,dm<\varepsilon.
   $$
3. For every $A\subset [-M,M]$, there exist $I_i,\ldots,I_k$ disjoint open intervals, such that
   $$
   \int_{-M}^M\left|\chi_A-\sum_{j=1}^k\chi_{I_j}\right|\,dm<\varepsilon.
   $$
4. Suitably combining 2. and 3. we obtain that $f$ is $L^1$-approximated by Riemann-type step functions.
5. After that you know what to do.